# Collections account on one credit report yet CreditKarma reports my scores are almost the same. Why?

Tags: credit-score, credit-report, debt-collection

I've been fighting with the credit reporting agencies to get an incorrect collections account removed from my report. Two of the three have complied, but TransUnion is being very stubborn. It's been quite a few months since the other reports were updated.

When I checked CreditKarma last night (which provides scores from Equifax and Transunion) I noted that it does report a collection on my TU report and not on my EQ report, yet the scores are almost identical. TU is two points lower than EQ. As this is the only negative item on my reports, I would have expected TU to have a much larger delta from EQ.

What could be the cause?

I'm concerned that perhaps EQ is still lowering my score due to influence from other reporting agencies, but this doesn't seem likely. It also seems unlikely that TU is disregarding their information since it contradicts the majority of the three bureaus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert on the wizardy behind credit scoring, but my first guess was that TransUnion is not using the disputed item to calculate your score, despite still showing the item.

I went digging to see if this is true and it seems to be. From [credit.com blog entry](http://blog.credit.com/2017/10/what-happens-when-you-dispute-something-on-your-credit-report-112460/):

> When an account is documented as disputed, “it is temporarily excluded
>   from consideration by the VantageScore model,” explains Jeff
>   Richardson, spokesperson with VantageScore. Similarly, “the FICO Score
>   algorithm excludes account activity that is in dispute,” says FICO
>   spokesperson Jeffrey Scott.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I know they all have their own formulas but I assume the scores they produce are comparable. That would explain the 'bad' report being roughly equivalent to the 'good' ones. I wonder how long it takes for the score to adjust downwards again, as I've been sending in disputes sporadically.